# Why my "change" event hasn't worked as intended?

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, so I'm practicing my JS and HTML, my current code looks like this:

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="answer"]:checked').checked = false;
let Select = document.querySelector('input[name="answer"]');
Select.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  alert(event.target.value)
})
```

```html
<div>
  <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" checked="checked">1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">2</label>
</div>
```

My aim is to cancel first radio's "checked", then add an event that will show each of radio's value whenever I choose/"checked" it, but as you may notice, so far the alert will only shows up if I choose the first radio. So if I may ask, where did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

p.s. For the sake of practicing, the HTML has to stay the same. No adding Id or other selector.

Comment: `document.querySelector` will return the first element that does match the passed selector. To get all such elements, use `document.querySelectorAll`, but beware this returns a NodeList that you need to iterate over to access each elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You only get the first with querySelector
2. The querySelector(...:checked)  will work because you can only have one checked radio
3. I really like to delegate - [it is recommended and makes a lot of sense](https://www.google.com/search?q=delegate+vs+querySelectorAll)

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="answer"]:checked').checked = false;
let radDiv = document.getElementById('radioDiv');
radDiv.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  const tgt = event.target;
  if (tgt.matches("[type=radio][name=answer]")) { // check we have the right elements
    alert(tgt.value)
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="radioDiv">
  <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" checked="checked">1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: "You **need** to delegate" why do they "need" to do so? Not delegating works just fine. Delegating means that they need to write a far more complex handler that will take care of not firing when an other dev will append a completely unrelated element that also does fire a change event.

Comment: **I** do have absolute opinions when you wrote "you need to "? (...)

Comment: *During* my ranting.

Comment: Your change was made in the 5 minute grace period and hasn't been saved by the server. 06:10:19 is the time when you did post the first revision of this answer. You did edit your question just two seconds before I post my comment, yes it took me more than two seconds to write my comment.

Comment: Who is doing this don't know. Atleast comment what's wrong

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I forgot the difference between 'querySelector' and 'querySelectorAll'.

Comment: I did downvote this answer, not the other ones, and I already told what I don't like in this answer: simply throwing "you should use delegation" without a single word of the implications of doing so is a terrible advice.

Comment: Not downvoting terrible advice is.

Comment: What is terrible??? It is recommended by hundreds of developer and javascript authors to delegate clicks on multiple related elements - this is unsubstantiated opinionated harassment

Comment: No, I explained clearly what is wrong with your answer: delegation is not just adding one event handler to the parent. You need to make the logic to handle the event that you actually want. Failing to do so you open yourself to hell-to-debug bugs, because you'll end up receiving events that you were not supposed to receive. Please look up at event delegation and how it is done.

Comment: @Kaiido Please see updated answer - you were correct about being a bit too short on the code

Comment: @李伯均 Please see updated code for a narrower access to the elements

Comment: Nowadays we have `Element.matches` that helps a lot checking if you're handling the correct target.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for explanations in theses comments. I learned new things :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="answer"]:checked').checked = false;

let Select = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="answer"]');

 Select.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('change',function (event) {
    Select.forEach(e => alert(e.value));
 }))
```

```html
<div>
      <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" checked="checked">1</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">2</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: [...Select].forEach is useless, NodeList has a `forEach` method`

Comment: @Kaiido [...elements] is useful. You need it for map, filter etc anyway, so why not. Also  Older Edge do NOT have forEach on nodelists, so it is defensive coding

Comment: @mplungjan because they are not using `map` `filter` etc. They have created two Arrays from this NodeList only to use `.forEach` and right at the end they use the NodeList's `forEach`, for no apparent reason: they are lucky this method exists, otherwise their code would throw.

Comment: @Kaiido for no apparant reason? Support of more browsers is a very good reason.

Comment: @mplungjan the "for no apparent reason" applies to the last one, which is `NodeList.prototype.forEach` that does break any potential "support" reason for the 2 first [...Select]

Comment: @mplungjan "The last one", which is here since the first rev.

Answer (score -1):

```
let Select = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="answer"]');
Select.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
        alert(event.target.value)
    });
});
```

Use above for element selector instead of `querySelector` which returns a single object (first match)
`querySelectorAll` returns an array of elements.